# Why can high-rep OS users edit a question or answer directly, but not approve an edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have a pretty high reputation on Stack Overflow. I'm able to edit a question or answer and my edits are published directly, without review.

However, if somebody else edits a question/answer, I can't approve that edit, nor can I "improve". I sometimes find questions that need improvement, but when I go to edit them I find that another answer is pending. The edits may not address the improvement I feel is needed, but I can't publish my edits until their edits are approved.

It seems to me that once you're able to publish edits to questions without review, you should be able to approve other's edits, or "improve" them as well.

Comment: Too many robo-reviewers. They don't bother with improving edits though as it's too much work for them.

Comment: Are you unable to approve or improve edits at all? From your question, I got the impression that you can't click the "Improve Edit" button in the review dialog box.

Comment: @4castle From the question I get the impression OP is _not_ in the review queue. Rather, he is trying to make his own edit, and is blocked by one pending review, or he is looking at the edit history, not the review queue, for the post and wants to edit/improve/approve that edit from there.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver That's what I thought too, but in addition to the review queue, there's a dialog box that appears when you click "edit" which asks you to review an existing edit before submitting your own.

Comment: @4castle Could be that's exactly the answer he needs, not having noticed that, or understood it, before. I guess a dialog box is hard to miss, but its meaning might have escaped him, or didn't register correctly as the solution to his issue. BTW, possibly because I lack the rep to review, I've never seen that dialog.

Comment: I can improve edits. It just puzzled me that I can't approve an edit immediately or improve it immediately. This is indeed a duplicate question. My bad for not looking harder before posting.